# How to get specific block(group) based on child node's value in XPath from the XML?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

I am newbie for XPath. I have the following XML file.
Here my xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<items>
   <item>
      <country>India</country>
      <referenceId>IN375TP</referenceId>
      <price>400</price>
   </item>
   <item>
      <country>Australia</country>
      <referenceId>AU120ED</referenceId>
      <price>15</price>
   </item>
   <item>
      <country>United Kingdom</country>
      <referenceId>UK862RB</referenceId>
      <price>20</price>
   </item>
</items>
```

I want the following `<item>` tag as an output:

```
<item>
  <country>Australia</country>
  <referenceId>AU120ED</referenceId>
  <price>15</price>
</item>
```

Note: Please use condition like `/items/item[referenceId/text()="AU120ED"]`

Comment: Based on what value?

Comment: Where did you get that xml from?

Comment: Should I use ElementTree here?

Comment: You have two different opening an closing tags `<referenceId>AU120ED</date>`, are there many `items` or just the one?

Comment: Oops!!!!!!! Sorry
I modified that

Comment: Only one `items` in the file and each `item` has unique referenceId value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find the item by country, you can use an xpath specifying you want to find the item in items that have the *text=country_name*:

```
from lxml.etree import parse, HTMLParser

xml = parse("check.xml",HTMLParser())

print(xml.find("//items//item[country='Australia']"))
<Element item at 0x7f40faa28950>
```

If you actually want to search be referenceid, just change to `item[referenceid='AU120ED']`:

```
print(xml.find("//items//item[referenceid='AU120ED']"))
<Element item at 0x7f02c0c24998>
```

For *xml*:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

xml = et.parse("check.xml")

print(xml.find(".").find("./item[referenceId='AU120ED']"))
```